# access class property set inside of promise

Tags: javascript, node.js, ecmascript-6

Coming from a heavy background in PHP I am struggling with some aspects of node/js.

```
const ldap = require('ldapjs');

class LdapClient {
  constructor({
    url,
  }) {
    this.isBound = null;
    this.client = ldap.createClient({ url });
  }

  authenticate(credentials) {
    const _this = this;

    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
      return this.client.bind(credentials.username, credentials.password, (err, res) => {
        if (err) {
          this.client.unbind();
          return reject(err);
        }

        _this.isBound = true;

        return resolve(res);
      });
    });
  }
}
```

```
const client = new Client({url: ''})

const credentials = {
  'username': '',
  'password': ''
}

client.authenticate(credentials)
  .then(() => {
    console.log('authenticated');
    console.log('race = ' + client.isBound); // SHOWS TRUE
  })
  .catch(e => {
    console.log(e);
  })

console.log(client.isBound); // SHOWS NULL... WANT TRUE (RACE ISSUE as consoles before PROMISE)
```

I am trying to access the `isBound` property outside of the promise return where it is set to true inside the authentication method on success.

However as you can see there appears to be a possible race condition?

Is there a way to handle this...

Thanks

Comment: the way is to handle it when the promise is resolved... this is actually what promises are made for

Comment: You're checking a value that is set asynchronously synchronously. You'll check it before it's set, then when it resolves you're checking it again and getting the true

Comment: you don't need to _this in your code since you're using arrow functions which are set lexically, https://github.com/getify/You-Dont-Know-JS/blob/master/this%20%26%20object%20prototypes/README.md

Comment: Is it just me or is the question a little... off form it's intended focus? Would it be better a `Race condition while accessing value set inside a promise chain from outside the promise chain` ?

Comment: "*I am trying to access the isBound property outside of the promise*" - why are you trying to do that? Doing it outside of the `then` callback means doing it *before* the promise resolves

Answer (score 4):

It is not a race condition. It's working fine as expected. There are two `console.logs` in your code. The first one is in promise and the other one is outside the promise.

Your call goes into asynchronous mode, and the last `console.log` get executed sequentially as the next command in order, which at that time, the value of the variable was `null`. Your variable resolves later with the correct value.

If you have to perform further actions, you have to do it in the `.then()` portion of your `Client` method which will only execute when your `Promise` has resolved.

For example

```
Client().then() {//all of your post response related logic should be here}
```

Answer (score 0):

So you're misunderstanding something about promises. They're meant to be used for Asynchronous code, like so:

```
let p = new Promise(resolve => setTimeout(resolve, 1000, 'here'))

p.then(console.log)

//in one second 'here'
```

As you can see the then doesn't actually happen until AFTER the promise resolves. With asynchronous code that's whenever resolve gets called.

So what's happening in your code is as follows:

```
Create Promise -> set event loop callback

console.log(isBound) // false, but happens first because it's called sync

Promise resolves // true
```

so really in your promise resolution is the first place you're even going to be able to check it successfully. If you return it from the call you can chain there and make sure the scope is continued later.

```
let a = 0
let p = Promise.resolve(a)
  .then(a =>{
    a += 2;
    return a;
  })
  .then(a => console.log(a) || a)

console.log(a) // 0

p == p.then(a =>{
  a += 4;
  return a;
})
.then(console.log) // false because promises aren't equal and .then/.catch return new promise chains
// 2
// 6
```

The 2,6 and the false comparison may print out of order because of the event loop, however if you keep it all in the same lexical scope then you'll still have access to `a` or `this` within the confines of your promise chain.

---

Side note: You don't need to reference `_this` versus `this` with arrow function inside class methods. They will lexically scope and thus this will be bound to the local scope of that function. More information can be found at [You Don't know JS](https://github.com/getify/You-Dont-Know-JS/blob/master/this%20%26%20object%20prototypes/README.md)

Answer (score -1):

You're trying to set `isBound` when the promise is created, not when it's resolved.

Rather than returning the promise directly from the `authenticate()` method, you can store it in a variable, call `.then()` on it, and return the promise chain at that point.

```
authenticate(credentials) {
  // create your promise and store it
  let authPromise = new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    ...
  })

  // handle the promise and set isBound before returning the chain
  return authPromise.then(res => {
    _this.isBound = true
    return res
  })
}
```

This can be written with fewer lines, but this is meant to illustrate promise chaining and interception before returning.

**ADDITIONALLY** Your final `console.log()` is outside of your promise handler (a `.then()`) so it's always going to be null since that code gets run synchronously, before the authenticate async function has time to complete.

```
client.authenticate(credentials)
  .then(res => {
    // you MUST do all your async-dependant operations inside
    // promise handlers like this
    console.log(client.isBound);
  })
```

Comment: Aren't arrow functions bound to lexical scope and thus a this call is fine and _this not needed?

Comment: @RobertMennell yes, but I'm trying to retain as much of the original code to illustrate the main point which is the promise chaining.

Comment: you could just make a note in your answer so that future learners won't develop the same anti pattern

Comment: @RobertMennell we've made a note of it here in the comments. That's a more appropriate place to discuss code quality versus the problem space.

Comment: Isn't `_isbound` set asynchronously in the callback from `client.bind`, in the code path taken if no error occurred,immediately before resolving the promise?

Comment: @Soviut thanks for the code, however handling the promise inside the `authenticated()` method as you show still does not allow me to use the final `console.log()`. I need to read more on promises as I can see it catching me out :/

Comment: @mybigman you can't use your final console log outside of `.then()`.